# How to add header parameter at Linking.openURL(url)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I want to open web URL to start the corresponding activity with application. However I need to add header parameter to access web URL.

> Linking.openURL(url).catch(err => console.error('An error occurred',
>   err));

I don't find the the way of adding header parameter at [react native doc](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/linking.html).

Answer (score 0):

i think there is no way to set a request header while opening links with Linking API.

So whatever you want to pass to the application needs to be passed through the URL by appending some paramenters.

Example:

```
let url = 'http://example.com';
url +='?myparam=myvalue';
```

then you parse the url from the requested application to get the params.

If security is a concern then you may encrypt your `myvalue` and decrypt it on your requested application.

Comment: Thanks Inus. you mean I have to add query parameters in url. I feel it is exposing so that I want to add header parameter.

Comment: Yes, if you need to pass something to the application with Linking API then thats the only way i can think of.